# Generic method to retrieve data from a property of superclass

Tags: java

I have some entities extended with a generic BaseEntity which have a Id property and I want to do a method where I pass an entity and retrieve that id, i.e.

**BaseEntity**

```
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    // Getters and setters
}
```

**Entity**

```
public class Entidad extends BaseEntity {

    protected String name;

    protected String image;

    protected Set<ContactForm> contactForms = new HashSet<ContactForm>();

}
```

(ContactForm also extends from BaseEntity)
And I want do something like this:

```
List<Long> longlist;

longlist = retrieveIds(entidad.getContactForms);

[...]

public List<Long> retrieveIds(Set<BaseEntity> entidades){
        List<Long> lista = new ArrayList<Long>();

        for(BaseEntity entidad : entidades){
            lista.add(entidad.getId());
        }

        return lista;
    }
```

It's possible? How?

Comment: Have you tried this? And if so did you get any errors?

Comment: @Edd Showing already. Just asking for an idea to return that id.

Comment: Yes, and I cant't compile, and the IDE suggest me to change method parameters...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is possible.

Just create a method in your super class and override that method in all child's which return id of that class.

Comment: Can you show me an example, it souns like I will write a overrided method for every entity

Answer (score 0):

Create a method getId() to return the Id of BaseEntity

**BaseEntity**

```
    public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable{
       private Long id;
       public Long getId() {
           return this.id;
       }
    }
```